# Suma de columna condicionada con otra

Tags: oracle

Tengo el siguiente query en oracle

```
SELECT DFD_ID_DFDC,
    DFD_FDC_ID_FDC,
    DFD_DCD_CODIGO,
    DCD_KG_DEMOSTRADOS_POLIZA
    FROM TBL_CMP_DFDC "dfdc"        
    INNER JOIN F_DOCCOMPROMISODESTINO "dcd" ON "dfdc".DFD_DCD_CODIGO = "dcd".DCD_CODIGO
    WHERE DFD_FDC_ID_FDC = 1564;
```

Esto me trae el siguiente resultado [image: Resultado de consulta]

Necesito tener la suma total de la columna DCD_KG_DEMOSTRADOS_POLIZA pero no se puede repetir el valor de 17000 ya que la columna DFD_DCD_CODIGO tiene dos veces el código 12142 repetido quiero hacer el DISTINCT para esa columna pero no he podido hacerlo. al hacer la suma total de la columna con SUM(DCD_KG_DEMOSTRADOS_POLIZA) me trae 573257 cuando debería traer 556257. Gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` no funciona como esperas porque la columna `DFD_ID_DFDC` tiene valores únicos, si esta columna no es relevante para esta consulta puedes quitarla y `DISTINCT` te traerá un solo registro de 17000.

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- DFD_ID_DFDC,
    DFD_FDC_ID_FDC,
    DFD_DCD_CODIGO,
    DCD_KG_DEMOSTRADOS_POLIZA
FROM TBL_CMP_DFDC "dfdc"        
INNER JOIN F_DOCCOMPROMISODESTINO "dcd" ON "dfdc".DFD_DCD_CODIGO = "dcd".DCD_CODIGO
    WHERE DFD_FDC_ID_FDC = 1564;
```

Si esta columna es importante necesitarías agrupar los registros primero o dependiendo de la distribución de columnas entre tus dos tablas, hacer una subconsulta con una de ellas.